# Update property of React component in a separate component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a React MaterialUI `AppBar`component with property `title` , that I am changing based on the value returned by `window.location.pathname`. So as the page/url changes, the title will change with it. Looks something like below:

```
<AppBar
title={this.renderTitle()}
/>

renderTitle() {
if (window.location.pathname === '/home'
 return 'home';
} else if (window.location.pathname === '/login'
return 'login';
}
```

The issue I am running into is that `renderTitle()` does not get executed if a different component (so not the `AppBar`) causes the page/url change.

E.g. another separate React component on the page triggers the page to change, which I'd hoped with trigger `renderTitle()`, but it doesn't... thus the `title` property never updates. So if I am navigating from `/home` to `/login`, the following will happen:

1. pathname is `/home`
2. user presses a button which runs a function, `submit()`, which is used to change the page w/ react-router
3. `renderTitle()` is run at this point, but `window.location.pathname` is still returning the previous page
4. `submit()` changes the page to `/login`
5. `window.location.pathname` is now correctly set to `/login`, but it is too late as `renderTitle()` has already been run

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) library. 
From documentation:

> react-document-title provides a declarative way to specify document.title in a single-page app.
>   This component can be used on server side as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your component that renders AppBar is an actual route you can just read the pathname from the props that react router injects.

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="about" component={About} />
     <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
       <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
     </Route>
   </Route>
 </Router>
```

For example in App, About, Inbox and Message you have access to the router props. And you can also pass the props to their children.

```
render() {
  return (
   <AppBar
     title={this.renderTitle(this.props.location.pathname)}
   />
  );
}
```

And in your function just use the parameter to return the correct result. Now because you are using props your component will update automatically when they change.